# Meaning of Scale Out Limit to No in Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

What does it mean when 'Enforce Scale Out Limit' is set to 'No' in Function App?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the term denotes, **`Scale Out Limit`** represents the number of instances that the current Function App can scale out.

You can set a maximum count if you enable this

Comment: Thank you! If I set to 'No', can this value go above 200?

Comment: you can see the limit here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling#understanding-scaling-behaviors